# One-parameter group of diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

I'm studying differential varieties using Tu's book and for now I have this exercise to solve.

$M = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $X = x \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} - y \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \in X(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Find the flow of $X$ and show that $X$ is complete. If possible, determine the one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms of $M$ generated by $X$.

As a sanity check I'd like to see if my way through this exercise is correct. I'm finding this subject rather dense.

First of all, to find the flow for $X$ I'll have to solve an 1st order ODE and from that, find an integral curve. If it is maximal, then $X$ is complete, right?

The integral curve I got was $c(t) = (K_1 e^t, K_2 e^{-t})$, where $K_1$ and $K_2$ are constants that I'd find knowing a point that passes through this curve. As $c(t)$ has no restrictions for $t$, I can define it for all real $t$'s, right?

I believe the (global) flow of this vector field is

$$
F : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \quad (t, ( x, y )) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} K_1 e^t & 0 \\ 0 & K_2 e^{-t} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix} := F_t(x,y)
$$

Now, what would my one-parameter diffeomorphism group be?
I'm thinking that for each parameter $t$, I'd have a different curve, therefore I need to consider the application

$$
t \mapsto F_t
$$
and $F_t \circ F_s = F_{s + t}$. The group in question would then be <$ F_t : t \in \mathbb{R} $>?

Comment: You are totally right, the one parameter subgroup is $\langle F_t\rangle$. Moreover, the flow is said to be complete because for all $(x,y)$, $F_t(x,y)$ is defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I'm confused as to what is it that we're calling complete. Is the flow or the vector field complete?

Comment: In fact it does not really matter. A vector field on a manifold $M$ is said to be complete if its flow $F$ is defined on all $\mathbb{R}\times M$, which I called above a complete flow. With this convention, a vector field is complete if and only if its flow is complete!

Comment: Oh, great! It makes sense then. Thank you very much for your reply!